# how to get SQL generated by Pear MDB2 without executing it?

Tags: php, sql, pear, mdb2

I'm working with Pear MDB2 with PHP 5.3.  I'm coding a project that updates a DB and before I let it start changing data, I'd like to see what the SQL queries generated by autoPrepare() and execute() look like before actually executing them.

I plan to create and execute an update query like this:

```
    $stmt = $db->extended->autoPrepare($tableName, $tableColumns,
    MDB2_AUTOQUERY_UPDATE, 'id = ' . $db->quote(12345, 'integer'),
    $tableColumnTypes));

    $res =& $stmt->execute($tableColumnValues);
```

I already know that I can see the SQL generated by `autoPrepare()` with placeholders for the values by accessing `$stmt->query`.  I'd like to see the completed SQL generated by `execute()`, with values substituted for placeholders, ***without actually sending the query to the DB***.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepared statements are compiled on the server-side, so you can't see them before they execute. Per example, in MySQL, if you want to execute a prepared statement, what MDB2 actually does is:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ?';
SET @baz = 'baz';
EXECUTE stmt USING @baz;
```

The server never "returns" the actual query it executed. If you want to see what query *was* executed, you'll have to set-up a query log.

Per example, in MySQL (my.cnf):

```
[mysqld]
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql_queries.log
general_log = 1
```

The query log would show, for the query example above:

```
Query     PREPARE stmt FROM 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ?';
Query     SET @baz = 'baz';
Query     EXECUTE stmt USING @baz;
Execute   SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = 'baz';
```

Comment: Oh, I see...  I think I'd heard about that long before, but I'd forgotten it.  Is it any different with the Pear MDB2 `autoExecute()` (not `autoPrepare()`) method?  The documentation ( http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-auto.php ) seems to suggest that the query will contain the columns values rather than placeholders.

Comment: @L S: From what I can see in the code, `autoExecute` calls `autoPrepare`, so there wouldn't be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r ($db->last_query, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but doesn't this work only ***after*** the call to `$stmt->execute()` has completed?  I need to access the completed SQL statement ***before*** that.